# Cyanogenmod 10.1 becomes unstable with usage?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, crashes, samsung-galaxy-mini

Does CM 10.1 become more and more unstable with usage? I have a Galaxy Mini S5570 running [CM 10.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2085347). After flashing the ROM my phone works fine for one or two weeks. But soon my phone starts crashing more often. The phone starts rebooting every now and then. Apps (especially Camera.apk) start crashing often even though I haven't installed any new apps. This doesn't happen for the for the first few days after flashing the ROM. Is there any fix for this? Any patch available so that my phone can run smoothly even after 2 weeks?

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, I would suggest asking in the CM forum: http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/forum/666-samsung-galaxy-mini-tass/

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't run the "Addon Apps" like "RAM Manager" or the "Seeder" script. I am not sure if you are using those, but the RAM manager could cause instability because it forces applications to close to "free ram".

The need to free RAM is a myth, if an application kills other apps, to free up some RAM, the OS will find something else to fill that RAM. Android does not want free RAM, it sees free RAM as wasted RAM.

As for "Seeder", if you are running that, I would either try updating, if you don't have the latest, or fresh install official CM without this script. Even the developer of this is acknowledging that it has been causing instability, like locking and reboots.

The biggest issue, really, that I see is that you are trying CM 10.1 on a device that has not been supported by CM for some time. This device's last official build was [CM 7.2](http://get.cm/?device=tass). So another reason you are seeing instability is because you are trying to run a version of Android on hardware that really doesn't support it. The CM team usually only drops support for a device when they can no longer get the latest builds to run on the device.

Comment: I flashed the ROM with and without the performance scripts but ended up with the same result. Does CM 10.1 store any cache that could possibly use up memory? How is it that the ROM runs smoothly in the beginning?